# Angular 4 Modules call each others

Tags: angular, circular-dependency

Let's say I have 2 modules : Customers / Orders like this :

```
/customers
    /customers-list.component.html
    /customers-list.component.ts
    /customers-details.component.html
    /customers-details.component.ts
    /customers-create.component.html
    /customers-create.component.ts
    /customers.service.ts
    /customers.module.ts

/orders
    /orders-list.component.html
    /orders-list.component.ts
    /orders-create.component.html
    /orders-create.component.ts
    /orders.service.ts
    /orders.module.ts
```

Both are using their own services (by using `providers` in module)

`orders.module` import the `customers.module` because in my `orders-create.component.ts`, I have a form where I can add a new order for a client. If the client do not exist, I can press a button and the `customers-create.component` is display.

But now, I need to add the list of the `Orders` for a given customer in my `customers-details.component` by calling the `orders-list.component`.

But I can't import the `Orders` module in my `Customers Module` because of circular dependency.

So : what is the best approach in this kind of situation? Do I need to create a shared module for my `orders-list.component`?

Comment: Make a new module that takes in both of those modules, and the new one has the combined layout components.

Comment: What do you mean @ps2goat ? Have you an example?

Answer (score 1):

> Both are using their own services (by using providers in module)

I suppose it's a wrong approach, you should have isolated (from logic) service to handle request (like API service) which would be defined once and could be reused anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a third module that *composes* the views you are looking for.  That allows you to continue to have domain-specific components (`order` and `customer`), but create different, but still reusable, pages.

E.g.:

```
/pages
  /customer-view.component
  /orders-create.component.ts
```

Your `customer-view.component` would use the `customers-details.component` and the `orders-list.component` to create the full view you describe.

Your `orders-create.component.ts` should live in this new module, as well, since it uses the customer component.

* disclaimer: name the module what you wish, it is merely an example.